# Function definition problems (No instance for … arising from)

Tags: haskell

I have defined the following function to find the penultimate element of a list of something (Int, string...)

```
myButLast :: [a] -> a
myButLast [] = error "myButLast: empty list"
myButLast [x, _] = x
myButLast (_:xs) = myButLast xs
```

When I test it with hspec

```
  it "returns an error for list of one element" $ do
   myButLast [42] `shouldThrow` anyException
```

I get the following error

> No instance for (Num (IO a0))
>         arising from the literal `42'
>       Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num (IO a0))
>       In the expression: 42
>       In the first argument of`myButLast', namely `[42]'
>       In the first argument of`shouldThrow', namely `myButLast [42]'

What does it mean and how to fix it ? May be a constraint of class needed?

I want to handle String and list of anything in myButLast. All my other tests with multiples elements works.

Comment: `myButLast [x, _] = x` matches a list with exactly two elements. If you want to match a list with one element: `myButLast [x] = x` or `myButLast (x:[]) = x`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shouldThrow` has the type `Exception e => IO a -> Selector e -> Expectation`. This means that the first argument should be in the IO monad. In order to use pure functions, you can use the `evaluate` function:

```
evaluate (myButLast [42]) `shouldThrow` anyException
```

Incidentally, you might want to test for the specific error to make sure it doesn't get mistakenly changed at some point:

```
evaluate (myButLast [42]) `shouldThrow` errorCall "myButLast: empty list"
```

Comment: What is the import for evaluate ?